# pdflatex error first time compiling in texstudio

Tags: pdftex

Messages:
Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Quickstart Article 1".tex

Sorry, but pdflatex.exe did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\pdflatex.log

Process exited with error(s)
I have saved pdflatex log - see below:

> 2019-01-26 18:16:11,827-0500 INFO  pdflatex - starting with command
>   line: pdflatex --version 2019-01-26 18:16:11,833-0500 INFO  pdflatex -
>   allowing known shell commands 2019-01-26 18:16:11,833-0500 INFO 
>   pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes 2019-01-26
>   18:16:11,837-0500 INFO  pdflatex - finishing with exit code 0
>   2019-01-26 18:16:16,064-0500 INFO  pdflatex - starting with command
>   line: pdflatex -draftmode -interaction=nonstopmode --disable-installer
>   C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/S14964.tex 2019-01-26
>   18:16:16,069-0500 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
>   2019-01-26 18:16:16,070-0500 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output)
>   from (to) processes 2019-01-26 18:16:16,093-0500 INFO  pdflatex -
>   going to create file: pdflatex.fmt 2019-01-26 18:16:19,096-0500 INFO 
>   pdflatex - finishing with exit code 1 2019-01-26 18:16:19,886-0500
>   INFO  pdflatex - starting with command line: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1
>   -interaction=nonstopmode "Quickstart Article 1.tex" 2019-01-26 18:16:19,892-0500 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
>   2019-01-26 18:16:19,892-0500 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output)
>   from (to) processes 2019-01-26 18:16:19,944-0500 INFO  pdflatex -
>   installing package nag triggered by tex/latex/nag\nag.sty 2019-01-26
>   18:16:19,944-0500 FATAL pdflatex - Administrator mode cannot be
>   enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.
>   2019-01-26 18:16:19,944-0500 FATAL pdflatex - Info:  2019-01-26
>   18:16:19,944-0500 FATAL pdflatex - Source:
>   Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp 2019-01-26 18:16:19,944-0500
>   FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1272 2019-01-26 18:16:19,944-0500 INFO 
>   pdflatex - finishing with exit code 1 2019-01-26 18:16:22,820-0500
>   INFO  pdflatex - starting with command line: pdflatex -draftmode
>   -interaction=nonstopmode --disable-installer C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/y14964.tex 2019-01-26
>   18:16:22,825-0500 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
>   2019-01-26 18:16:22,826-0500 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output)
>   from (to) processes 2019-01-26 18:16:22,871-0500 INFO  pdflatex -
>   finishing with exit code 1

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! As I understand it, the system try to install the `nag`  package, and can't do it because you installed MiKTeX for a single user. Try to install it with MiKTeX console, then recompile.

Comment: I tried installing MikTex for anyone using my computer (i.e.,not a single user).  But now I get a different error from the MiKTeX Setup Wizard:

Comment: MiKTeX Setup Wizard                 The operation could not be completed for the following reason:       The executed process did not succeed.                         
 Details:  C:\ProgramFiles\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe,   exitcode = "1"